# How to send a notification by email for an user when press a button action

Tags: python, django

I am new programer in Django, but i need create a notification for an user when press a button in a form in django.
Most information: 
We are developing an application than receive request from a portal and show this request in a list form, I have this list of request with two buttons, one is accept request and the other is refuse request. We need send an email for user when the request is refused or acepted.
Do you have any code related? Any help will very appreciated

send a email message for the user[Example of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIuYx.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Django docs. for sending email topic is clear enough ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/ ). you can start to add settings for the email backend in settings.py. what you need to do is just add set up SMTP server arguments, this example for gmail

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your-username@gmail.com'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'your-username@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your-password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

for both buttons, you can create an api that call send_email function.